# Need help in GeoServer Performace Testing using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using GeoServer 2.18 on my side & wanted to do performance testing.

Objective :

- I am using J meter for performance testing.
- My goal is to test a particular WFS service having basic parameters such as 'GetFeature','service', 'version','outputformat'.
- When I access my WFS url in web browser it downloads data in csv format as per url.
- While in J meter, it shows an exception for certain requests.

Details :

- URL :  **`https://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:layer&outputFormat=csv`**

My questions :

- Any idea why it's showing an exception ?
  [image: exception]
  [image: GIS data]
- If I change an output format as 'fff' then why it shows response code as '200'(OK)?
- Any document available for response code ?
  [image: Response data]
  [image: Response code 200]

Answer (score 1):

- `Any idea why it's showing an exception ?`  - it's server-side error, check your application logs for the reason. From JMeter side you can troubleshoot the issue by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

  ```
   javax.net.debug=all
  ```

  and the following lines to [*log4j2.xml* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/):

  ```
  <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
  <Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug" />
  ```

  JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change
- with regards to `response too large to be displayed` - [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener limits the maximum response size, to disable this limitation add the next line to *user.properties* file:

  ```
   view.results.tree.max_size=0
  ```
- `If I change an output format as 'fff' then why it shows response code as '200'(OK)?` - again, this is how your server is set up, JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, if you want to check the response for errors you will need to add i.e. [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)